# Can a context switch between threads of the same process occure during signal handling?

Tags: linux, signals, context-switch

Logic tells me that in Linux, the OS does not allow context switchwes between threads of the same process during the operation of a signal handler, but I wasn't able to find anything concrete about it online. Is my assumption correct?

I wasn't able to find any similar question here

Comment: Why would running two threads in parallel on separate CPUs be OK, but not switching?

Comment: One problem at a time :)
I know that I shouldn't assume that the answer regarding multithreading on a single processor the same as for multiple processors.

Comment: I'm just asking what specific logic tells you that context switches are not allowed while not also telling you that running on multiple processors is not allowed.